# Web scraping an HTML table in R taking huge time

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

Folks,
I'm trying to **scrape** a link which has just around 1000+ records but its taking hours to get them..Wondering if I'm doing anything wrong or ways to load this into a table.

```
urlString = "https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/selector-data/primary-category/1/equity/?tab=snapshot&output=html-data"
urlString <- URLencode(paste0(urlString,""))

#Reading the HTML code from the website and process the text
getHTML <- xml2::read_html(urlString, options = "HUGE")

#This one keeps running endlessly and doesn't load the table
mytable <- data.frame(getHTML %>% html_table(fill = T, trim = T))
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is a JSON file. You need to read it by `jsonlite` first. And the HTML data is at `html_data` node, you read this node by `read_html`:

```
json <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://www.valueresearchonline.com/funds/selector-data/primary-category/1/equity/?tab=snapshot&output=html-data")
getHTML <- xml2::read_html(json$html_data)
mytable <- data.frame(getHTML %>% html_table(fill = T, trim = T))
```